# PHP - Checking for empty element in 2D array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks like the following

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "input1" => "Something"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "input2" => ""
  ]
]
```

Now the first element will always have some data.  It is the second element I am interested in.  At the moment, I am trying this

```
if(!empty($clientGroup[0][1]) || !empty($clientGroup[1][1]))
    var_dump("Some Data");
} else {
    var_dump("Both Empty");
}
```

The else should only be triggered if both elements are empty e.g.

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "input1" => ""
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "input2" => ""
  ]
]
```

If one of them have any data, the if should be triggered (so for the first array I showed, the if should be triggered).

How would I go about doing this, empty does not seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: What is going wrong? Does your first array generate "Some Data" or "Both Empty"?

Comment: Based on the answer you accepted, I assume you were always getting "Both Empty".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd level keys do not exist so you will always be told the values are empty. Change the line

```
if(!empty($clientGroup[0][1]) || !empty($clientGroup[1][1]))
```

to,

```
if(!empty($clientGroup[0]['input1']) || !empty($clientGroup[1]['input2']))
```

and you should get the results you're after.

Answer (score 1):

It's not realy 2D array because you have associative array inside an other array.

you must use key name (input1, input2) to access the value.

I recommend to use

```
if($retourdata[0]["input1"] !== "" || $retourdata[1]["input2"] !== "")
```